# Interact data from NodeJS server to AngularJS

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, axios

I have an nodejs app which display some data to the route /api/getTokens on port 3000 (localhost).
I'm actually trying to display these data on my angular app which run on port 4200.
Could you tell me how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Change url to `'/api/searchForReservation'`

```
export class AppComponent {
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
      this.http.get('/api/searchForReservation')
        .subscribe(data => {
          console.log('result', data);
        })
  }
```

Comment: Hello, it doesn't work.. GET http://localhost:4200/api/getTokens 404 (Not Found), core.mjs:6485 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found', url: 'http://localhost:4200/api/getTokens', ok: false, …}

Comment: It's okay, I just create a proxy file to display my server data on Angular localhost 4200